# vagrant up すると「SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL, errno 54」が出る

Tags: vagrant, macos, openssl

初歩的な質問で申し訳ありませんが、回答していただけると助かります。

ドットインストールにて[ローカル環境開発について学習している](http://dotinstall.com/lessons/basic_localdev_mac_v2/38506)中でエラーが出ました。動画の内容通りに進めていき、`vagrant init bento/centos-6.8` をした後、仮想マシンの IP アドレスを設定してから `vagrant up` をした際のエラーです。

```
An error occurred while downloading the remote file. The error
message, if any, is reproduced below. Please fix this error and try
again.

OpenSSL SSL_read: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL, errno 54
```

このように出てしまっています。
通常通り起動させるにはどうしたら良いでしょうか。
お願いいたします。

環境: macOS Sierra (10.12.6), OpenSSL 0.9.8zh 14 Jan 2016, Terminal

Comment: スタック・オーバーフローへようこそ！　エラーメッセージの最終行でググると分かりますが、エラー番号54は通信不可能だったことにより起こるものです。ターミナルで `openssl version` と打ったときの結果と、[macOS のバージョン](https://support.apple.com/ja-jp/HT201260)を教えてくださいませんか？

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。openssl version　を打つと　OpenSSL 0.9.8zh 14 Jan 2016　と出ました。バージョンは10.12.6でした。

Comment: ドットインストールと言うとおそらく[この回](http://dotinstall.com/lessons/basic_localdev_mac_v2/38506)をご覧になっているのだと思いますが、合っていますか？

Comment: はい、この回を学習しています。

Comment: ググったところ、他の errno に対しては「`rm ~/.vagrant.d/tmp/*` する」「何回か `vagrant up` してみる」「インターネット接続を確認する」「OpenSSLをバージョンアップする」などがヒットしますが、ピンポイントにこの errno について言及しているものは少ないですね……。念の為、`vagrant version` の結果も教えて頂けませんか？　また、上の方法の内最後のもの以外は簡単に行えて他への影響も小さいので、お時間あるときにお試しください。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。vagrant version　は　Installed Version: 1.9.8
Latest Version: 2.0.0　でした。vagrant up　を何度か試してみたところすぐに　A Vagrant environment or target machine is required to run this
command. Run `vagrant init` to create a new Vagrant environment. Or,
get an ID of a target machine from `vagrant global-status` to run
this command on. A final option is to change to a directory with a
Vagrantfile and to try again.　このように出てしまいます。

Comment: そのエラー自体は、`vagrant up` をするディレクトリを間違っているから出るのではないでしょうか？

Comment: ディレクトリが間違っている場合どのような対処をすれば良いでしょうか。

Comment: `vagrant init` によって `Vagrantfile` を作ったディレクトリに `cd` してから `vagrant up` してください。ドットインストールの動画通りなら、`MyCentOS` という名前のはずです。

Comment: 遅くなり申し訳ありません。nekketsuuu様のおかげで通常通り起動することができました、ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 1):

<sup>(この回答が直接今回のエラーに関与している訳ではないと思うのですが、質問者さんの環境ではこれで問題が解決したとのことですので、回答として投稿します。)</sup>

`vagrant up` を実行するカレント・ディレクトリを間違っているのかもしれません。`vagrant init` によって `Vagrantfile` を作ったディレクトリに `cd` してから `vagrant up` してください。ドットインストールの動画通りなら、`MyCentOS` という名前のはずです。

また、errno が異なる類似のエラーに関しては、検索すると「`rm ~/.vagrant.d/tmp/*` する」「何回か `vagrant up` してみる」「インターネット接続を確認する」「OpenSSLをバージョンアップする」などで解決したという記事が見つかります。ただしそれぞれ何故それで良いのかまでは確認していません。解決するための検索キーワードとしてご参考になればと思います。